# Command aggregate not authorized to run

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Having a strange issue with MongoDb permissions, my user successfully acceses the data in most collections and has `dbAdmin` and `readWrite` roles on the database but when listing documents from one collection I get:

```
Command aggregate failed: not authorized on DB to execute command { aggregate: "Customer", pipeline: [ { $limit: 250 }, { $group: { _id: 1, __result: { $sum: 1 } } } ], cursor: {} }
```

AFAIK `readWrite` should suffice for everything and the user is also `dbAdmin`

Using the latest version of MongoDb server and C# client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a permissions issue though the user permissions were fine and user could perform all the commands, when the user's credentials were actually used.

The issue was with my IoC/DI container which in certain cases did not fill in the Credentials on the MongoClient object thus the command was failing (since this happened only in one controller action the issue was a bit harder to debug).